# Zpanel and cron job with cakephp

Tags: php, ssh, cron, cakephp-2.0, izpanel

I have tried and browsed a lot regarding how to set cron job with CakePHP and zpanel

In zpanel I tried different types url

For example

1. domain_folder/app/cron_dispatcher.php /CampaignMasters/newsletter_find_cron(Error: script does not exist)

Then I tried a file  domain_folder/app/cronjob.php(Worked)

it worked but I am confused how can I call "domain_folder/app/cron_dispatcher.php /CampaignMasters/newsletter_find_cron" from cronjob.php

I am in a really twisted state, I have tried this for about 10 hours by trying many methods.

Any zpanel or CakePHP expert please just tell me the best way to set this as a cron job.

Can I add cron job through ssh in zpanel? If I can add this one through ssh "domain_folder/app/cron_dispatcher.php /CampaignMasters/newsletter_find_cron" Then it would be great. I am ready to try anything.

The OS is CentOS

Comment: First you need to create a command using cakephp: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html 

Then run that command in crontab.

Try the `crontab -e` command? It'll open up vim. Just dump your command and the occurrences in there.

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Comment: You got it to work? Awesome! :)

Comment: Yes, worked like a charm.. Post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to go all out :)

**Step 1**

Create a shell class so that you can call the actions from command line.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html

```
class HelloShell extends AppShell {
    public function main() {
        $this->out('Hello world.');
    }
}
```

**Step 2**

Try the command that you've just created via SSH or terminal:

```
Console/cake hello
```

You may have to run this command in your app directory:

```
cd yourapp/app
../Console/cake hello
```

**Step 3**

Create a cron job using cron tab

```
crontab -e
```

Vim or your default text editor will open.
Apply your cron command there.

```
* 00 * * 6 php your_app_path/lib/Cake/Console/cake.php hello
```

Checkout http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron to understand how occurrences work.

Save and done!